# Running maven test with a class name - How does Maven find the class?

Tags: java, class, maven, testing, directory

I have a project and this project has test files under /src/test/.

There are a lot of sub-folders under test. Package structure. And there are several test classes.
But I was told to run `mvn test -Dtest=<class_name>` from the root of the project. This is a single java file with all Integration test code.

As I am new to Maven, I am wondering how maven finds this file which is several folders down underneeth and executes it? Does it scan all files src/test/... and all its subfolders for this file and runs it?

Yes, it is a basic question.

Note: pom.xml does not have any references to this file specifically.
I know maven needs a file structure src/main and src/test. But I am not sure if it scans all folders underneeth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mvn test -Dtest=

`mvn` invoke the `maven processor`

`test` execute the `test phase` of the build lifecycle and all it's dependencies

`-Dtest=<class_name>` set system property that test uses to determine class to execute.

The `pom.xml` is used to setup the build lifecycle, you specify what golas will run in what phases for your build profile along with the dependencies required.

You can put system properties inside the pom but it is usually better to put them in the maven invocation.

Comment: So my question, does Maven scan all sub-folders to find the class name passed to it?

Comment: Scan is not the right word. It build a class path and then invokes the class from the class path just like Java would. If you use a testRunner they will usually scan the class path to look for any test classes. But that happens with or without maven.